# Javascript: Trouble Converting String to Number

Tags: javascript

Given the circumstances I have to use a node list to get at elements that I need to work with. I am able to use `.textContent` (or `.nodeValue`) to return a string that I need, but I am having trouble finding a way to get that string into any type of number. I need to have it in number form so I can perform calculations with it. I have tried `Number()`, `parseInt()`, etc. All return `NaN`. I am pretty new to JS so hopefully this is an easy issue to solve.

```
var siteActual = tdNodeListActual[36].textContent; // location of data
console.log(siteActual); // returns the value 1 as it should

var asd = Number(siteActual); // test variable to convert string to number
console.log(asd); // returns NaN
```

EDIT: I checked `.length` as one of you suggested and it was 2, so those saying it may be an invisible character are probably right. I am trying to make changes to a SharePoint page, that is why I am not familiar with what the markup is. Any suggestions on how to remove all but the number would be helpful.

Comment: try `parseInt(String)`

Comment: What's in siteActual? do you have an example? Number("1") works, that's why I'm asking again.

Comment: I guess another question is: how have you used `parseInt(...)` - on which element? I suppose more details would be necessary (i.e. some HTML sample on where you are getting the value from to begin with)

Comment: try logging `siteActual.length` and see if it's what you expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work as-is if the content is really just `1` (as should `parseInt`). So there must be something other than valid numbers in your content.

Sometimes there can be content that you can't see, e.g. in the example below the second `td` contains an invisible "zero-width space" character.

```js
var tdNodeListActual = document.querySelectorAll("td");

var good = tdNodeListActual[0].textContent;
var bad = tdNodeListActual[1].textContent;

alert(good + "==" + Number(good) + ", but " + bad + "==" + Number(bad))
```

```html
<table><tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>&#8203;2</td>
</tr></table>
```

You can remove all non-digit characters (except `.` and `,`) using a regex, e.g.:

```
siteActual = siteActual.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '');
```

Comment: I checked .length as one of you suggested and it was 2, so those saying it may be an invisible character are probably right. I am trying to make changes to a SharePoint page, that is why I am not familiar with what the markup is. Any suggestions on how to remove all but the number would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with regex - added to answer

Comment: Welcome. I've edited your comment from above into the question as I think it helps clarify - hope that's ok.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up from its resting place, but I have an additional question regarding what you've helped me with already. The regex you provided works good, but it is possible for some values to have a decimal point in them. How would I go about removing the blank space, but retaining a decimal point if one exists?

Comment: add the dot inside the `[]` - I added `.` and `,` above, in case you need to deal with international number formats

Comment: similarly, add a `-` if you need to deal with negatives

Answer (score 2):

Using `parseInt(...)`

Sample:

```
var siteActual = tdNodeListActual[36].textContent; // location of data
console.log(siteActual); // returns the value 1 as it should

var asd = Number(parseInt(siteActual)); // test variable to convert string to number
console.log(asd); // should return 1
```

Comment: What  purpose does parseInt serve?  If parseInt works, then Number works - also you should provide a radix on parseInt..

Comment: For what he wrote in the question, he already tried parseInt()

Comment: @MazzCris true, I didn't read that far down before I answered... asked again for more information in follow-up comments